# Tengo el siguiente problema y no hallo como solucionarlo, gracias de antemano

Tags: javascript, array, function, eliminar

La funcion 'buscaDestruye' recibe como argumento un array de enteros 'arreglo' y un entero 'num'.
Esta funcion tiene que eliminar los numeros del array que coincidan el numero recibido como argumento.
La función debe retornar el array sin los números sacados.
Ej: buscaDestruye([1, 2, 3, 4], 2) devuelve => [1, 3, 4]
**Nota: Si el numero se repite mas de una vez, tambien hay que eliminarlo.
Ej: buscaDestruye([1, 2, 3, 4, 1], 1) devuelve => [2, 3, 4]

Comment: Puedes usar [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter).

Comment: Disculpa, me puedes indicar como? Nunca he usado .filter(). Gracias

Comment: Por favor, replantea el título de tu pregunta para mostrar qué problemas tienes principalmente, y edita tu pregunta para demostrar lo que has intentado. Lee [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function buscaDestruye(arr,num){
  return arr.filter(function(el) {
      return el !== num;
  })
}

let arreglo = [1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4];
let numero = 2;

let result = buscaDestruye(arreglo,numero);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias